# Proving that $ e^z = z+\lambda$ has exactly $m+n$ solutions $z$ such that $-2\pi m<\Im z<2\pi n$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to prove that for $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$ and for $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ 
large enough, the equation:
$$ e^z = z+\lambda$$
has exactly $m+n$ solutions $z$ such that $-2\pi m<\Im z<2\pi n$, where $\Im z$ denotes the imaginary part of $z$.

I thought about looking at the rectangle $\pm R + 2\pi in, \pm R - 2\pi im$ and try to use Rouche's Theorem with:
$$f(z)=e^z-(z+\lambda)=P_{n+m}(z) + \sum_{k=m+n+1}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!} - (z+\lambda)$$

where:
 $$P_{n+m}(z) =\sum_{k=0}^{m+n}\frac{z^k}{k!} $$

is a polynomial of degree $m+n$, and all is left is to prove that:
 $$|P_{n+m}(z)| >  \left| \sum_{k=m+n+1}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!} - (z+\lambda)\right|$$

in the boundary of the rectangle. But I don't know how to do that (or even if this solution is the right way to go)

Thanks!

Comment: Try using the argument principle on your rectangle.

Comment: If you write $z = x + iy$ you obtain two equations, one for the modulus and the other for the argument of $e^z = e^x e^{iy}$. Then one variable can be eliminated and you obtain just one equation involving a tangent function from which the $2\pi$-periodicity is obvious.

Comment: The imaginary part $\Im z$ of a complex number $z$ is a **real number**. Modified the post accordingly.