# Show that $e^z = z + \lambda$ has exactly $m + n$ solution in a horizontal strip.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$,
show that for sufficient large $m$ and $n$,
then the equation $e^z = z + \lambda$ has exactly $m + n$ solutions in the horizontal strip
$\{- 2 \pi im < \operatorname{Im} z < 2 \pi i n\}$.

I tried to compute the increase in the argument of $f(z) = e^z - z + \lambda$ around the rectangle with vertices $R-2\pi im$, $R + 2 \pi in$, $-R + 2 \pi in$ and $-R + 2 \pi im$. When $R$ is sufficiently large, $f(x) \approx e^z$,
but then I got that the increase in the argument around the rectangle is $4\pi (m + n)$.
So what I did wrong?

Comment: One needs to divide by $2\pi$ to convert from the increase in argument to the net number of zeros. (btw, it looks like your rectangle is oriented in the wrong direction) That leaves just a factor of $2$ to locate.

Comment: @GregMartin Can you be more specific? According to my solution, there are 2(m+n) solutions in the strip. I don't know where is the extra 2 come from....

Comment: When the real part of $z$ is $-R$ the exponential function $e^z$ is tiny.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing that for large $m$ and $n$ the equation $e^z=z+\lambda$ has exactly $m+n$ solutions in the horizontal strip $\{-2\pi*i m&lt; Imz &lt; 2i\pi n\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744706/showing-that-for-large-m-and-n-the-equation-ez-z-lambda-has-exactly-mn)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I hope to use the argument principle to solve this problem, that link does not really solve my question. But your comment is very helpful though.